# Invalid column name for SQL Server in nested queries

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

Here is my `Orders` table:

```
Orders
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1), ---> PK
    OrderID int NOT NULL, ---> FK
    ProductID int NOT NULL,--> FK
    CustomerID int NOT NULL,-> FK
    Quantity int NOT NULL,
    TotalPrice int,
)
```

I want to get last `orderID` value from this table, so I get what query I need to execute. I get `OrderID` from last row with using nested query belong:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * 
      FROM dbo.Orders 
      ORDER BY OrderID DESC)
```

After I execute this query I get

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

error and invalid column name for `OrderID` in that query.

Could someone please say where my mistake at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put an alias on the sub query. So change this:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID
      FROM dbo.Orders 
      ORDER BY OrderID DESC)
```

To this:

```
SELECT tbl.OrderID 
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID
      FROM dbo.Orders 
      ORDER BY OrderID DESC) AS tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed out the table alias name

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * 
      FROM dbo.Orders 
      ORDER BY OrderID DESC) AS A
```